# jQuery window on load is firing too early. What else can I use? Javascript in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I'm learning jQuery and Javascript, and I'm trying to understand why my code is not working.

I'm doing this from inside a custom plugin in WordPress.

My javascript file with the function I'm trying to call is enqueued in the WordPress footer:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='..... gf_timer.js?ver=1.1.0.1'></script>
```

and my PHP is generating items like the following:

```
<div id="gf_timer_1">Placeholder</div>
<script type="text/javascript">$j=jQuery.noConflict(); $j(window).on('load',gfInitTimer(1));</script>
```

I just want to call the function gfInitTimer() after each div. I keep on getting an error "gfInitTimer is not defined".

So I added the onclick handler as a test and that's finding the function properly:

```
<div id="gf_timer_1" onclick="gfInitTimer(1)">Placeholder</div>
<script type="text/javascript">$j=jQuery.noConflict(); $j(window).on('load',gfInitTimer(1));</script>
```

I thought the `window.on('load',` should fire after the page and all scripts are loaded.

What am I missing?

Comment: I think you must do `$j(document).on('load',...` instead of `$j(window).on('load',...` . Try that.

Comment: try alert(window.onload) in your function to make sure the function is even being called or use $( document ).ready() to see if it changes anything

Comment: @Tushar: Thanks but when I try it's still: Uncaught ReferenceError: gfInitTimer is not defined

Comment: `jQuery.noConflict();
(function( $ ) {
  $(function() {
    // new code here
  });
}(jQuery)); // $ here is other Library`. `gfInitTimer` in your example must be defined before the load, of course. `<script>` tag should be in your head or load may have occurred. You should use external JavaScript, unless you don't want to cache it, as well.

Comment: @PHPglue Wow. That worked! I don't fully understand it, so I'll have to dive into it. But thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

if you want to load gfInitTimer right after the page is loaded try using ready as shown:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //run your gfInitTimer here
});
```

Comment: document.ready is a Jquery function, but is fired before document.onload